# Webmatrix Reset password

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider, simplemembership

I want to know how to set a password using mvc4 providers without knowing the old password ?

I want to make a forgot password function, where the user receives a secure link via email and then clicks the link, gets directed to the my application and then has to fill in only the new password, no security questions needed.

It was easy to do this with the membership providers that came with mvc3. I'm now using the simple membership providers that come with mvc4 and I'm having trouble getting it working.

the code so far looks as simple as:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser( cust.Email );
                String pass = user.GetPassword();

                Boolean success = WebSecurity.ChangePassword( cust.Email, pass, model.Password );
```

It currently gives error on the above line that calls GetPassword() with the error :

> Specified method is not supported.

I'll show the relevant section in the web.config also here :

```
<system.web>
      <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
          <providers>
              <clear/>
              <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
          </providers>
      </roleManager>
      <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
          <providers>
              <clear/>
              <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"
       enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" passwordFormat="Encrypted" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
       requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="5" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
       passwordAttemptWindow="10" />
          </providers>
      </membership>
```

Above I tried to add the attributes you use for the providers in mvc3 but it doesn't seem to be applicable here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken` generates and returns a unique string.

`WebSecurity.ResetPassword` uses that token to change the password.

Give the user a link to an action with the token as a parameter, then give them a simple form to change their password.

Comment: I'm glad it's so simple. I feel silly for not seeing this myself.

Comment: what John said :)  I was confusing ConfirmAccount and ResetPassword methods...pretty nice to be able to just use the (token, newPassword) parms and don't have to care about anything else

Comment: Dont forget to add a secret question field as well.